# using perl script to invoke cleartool commands using fmt

Tags: perl, clearcase

I use Perl scripts to run commands for several users in several VOBs on ClearCase. I have a list of the VOBs which I read in from a text file. I then loop on that list and do whatever ClearCase command I am trying to do. However, this time the script does not seem to work. If I print out the command to the screen then go and copy and paste it at the prompt it works fine. It just will not executed from the Perl script. The only difference I saw was the fmt characters but even when I remove that it does not execute. I tried first putting the fmt on the line directly then tried setting them to variables. You will see the first comment line is the one that failed but I left it there as an example of what I tried. The last two comments are from another script that I run like this that does work.

Code:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;

open(VOBS,"vobs.txt") || die "Can't open: !$\n";

my $u = '%u';
my $a ='%Ad';
my $n ='%N/n';
my $user='john';
my $ct = '/usr/atria/bin/cleartool';

while(my $newvobs=<VOBS>){

  chomp($newvobs);
  my $tag = $newvobs;
  print "\n $tag \n"; 
  print " $ct lstype -kind brtype -invob $tag | grep $user ";
  `$ct lstype -kind brtype -invob $tag | grep $user`;
  # `/usr/atria/bin/cleartool lstype -kind brtype -invob $tag -fmt '%u %Ad %N/\n' `;
  # print "\n cleartool rmtag -view  $tag \n";
  #`/usr/atria/bin/cleartool rmtag -view  $tag `;
}

close(VOBS);
```

Comment: cleartool command requires user interaction? or run smooth?

Comment: It will run smooth I will , when running, actually generate output to a txt file I send to the users to have them decide which branches to remove.

Comment: in that case, the " | grep $user" part should be deleted, it doesn't contribute to the command result

Comment: @Carole Any error message you could add?

Comment: Yes well I have the print so I can see what vob I am in and then I can see the command that it should be executing , then it should execute. However, from the screen I get just the two print statements like this:

Comment: Sorry did not mean to hit enter   so I get                   /vobs/pst
 /usr/atria/bin/cleartool lstype -kind brtype -invob /vobs/pst2 | grep john 
Then if I cut and copy the command printed out I get the results I would actually want displayed by the script                /usr/atria/bin/cleartool lstype -kind brtype -invob /vobs/pst | grep john 
2012-01-19     john        branch type "atm"
--02-27T09:15  john        branch type "bug_fix"
--11-15T10:06  john        branch type "earth_fix"
2011-02-16     john        branch type "firstcut"

Comment: @MiguelPrz actually I need the grep or maybe i need to do an outer loop because to just list the branches I would get hundreds for maybe 60 users. My overall goal is to have a list of all the branches owned by a specific user that covers all the vobs so they can obsolete old ones no longer in use.

Comment: @Carole, you didn't catch at Perl the result of the command execution, so I thought the "grep" command doesn't matters. You have to do: my $result = qx!$order!; and work with $result variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Your program runs, but is does not print anything.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $cmd = "cat";
`$cmd $0 | grep warning`;
```

Output: (nothing)

---

---

Easiest to fix. Last line

```
print `$cmd $0 | grep warning`
```

Output:

---

```
use warnings;
print `$cmd $0 | grep warning`;
```

---

If You need the exit code, replace last line with

```
my $exit = system("$cmd $0 | grep warning");
print $exit;
```

Output:

---

```
use warnings;
my $exit = system("$cmd $0 | grep warning");
0
```

---

Or use open to process output:

```
open my $fh, "$cmd $0 | grep warning|" or die;
while (<$fh>) { print $_; }
close $fh;
```

Output:

---

```
use warnings;
open my $fh, "$cmd $0 | grep warning|" or die;
```

---

But I could suggest something like bellow. Using AUTOLOAD the clearcase commands can be used as internal perl commands.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub AUTOLOAD {
    (my $sub = $::AUTOLOAD) =~ s/.*:://;
    print "---\n";
    system("time $sub @_");
    print "---\n";
}

my $cmd = "cat";
eval "$cmd($0)";
```

Output:

---

```
---
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub AUTOLOAD {
    (my $sub = $::AUTOLOAD) =~ s/.*:://;
    print "---\n";
    system("time $sub @_");
    print "---\n";
}

cat($0);
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 400%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2112maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+174minor)pagefaults 0swaps
---
```

---

Comment: thanks for the help the example you used with the my exit got it to run. I still have some issues with the grep working with the fmt because I think it sees it as one long string. However, I was able to get it to run in a format I could use. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here is a perl script which uses `-fmt`, "[Finding the latest baseline for a component](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21330134)":

#### Example:

```
ccperl StreamComp.pl mystream@\pvobtag | findstr {component}
```

#### Script "`streamcomp.pl`":

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $cmdout = `cleartool desc -fmt '%[latest_bls]CXp' stream:$ARGV[0]`;
my @baselines = split(/,/,$cmdout);
foreach $baseline (@baselines)
{
  $compname=`cleartool desc -fmt '%[component]p' $baseline`;
  printf("%-30s \t %s\n", $compname, $baseline);
}
```

It is a program working for a ClearCase UCM environment, but it could give you an idea of the kind of working statements (try without `grep` first) you could try to reproduce in your own base ClearCase program.